# How can I enforce quotas on roaming user profiles using samba?

Tags: samba

I am using a custom configuration of webmin from www.turnkeylinux.org to run a domain controller (basically Ubuntu Server 8.04/Hardy with Samba installed from the repositories).  I've set things up so that my users have roaming profiles that they can use at any of the windows clients that are joined to the domain.

I'd like to set a disk quota for each user that the windows client would enforce, one way or another.  That is, when they login and Samba downloads the users profile information the client, Samba would also send information about disk quota limits.  This way, if the user tries to download too many mp3s for example, windows will complain and prevent the user from using any more space.

I've tried setting a quota on the samba server with the quotas package, but that only creates log off problems when the user goes over their limit.  I think I can use the smbcquotas command in conjunction with windows' own quota tools, but I don't have the foggiest notion on how I might do this.

So my question is, can I get windows to enforce quotas on a per user basis using the samba server?

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781862%28WS.10%29.aspx) article it appears that I can limit the size of roaming profiles with Group Policy Objects.  At this point, I'm assuming that I will now have to set up LDAP in order to facilitate GPOs.